# How can I disable vsync in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp, directx, monogame, sharpdx

So as of about a year ago you can now unlock the framerate of a UWP application (or game) but I cannot find the documentation for it anywhere. Just 100's of sites saying that you can do it.

I am trying to do it in a C# UWP App with monogame and sharpdx as my directx wrapper.

How is this enabled?

Where is the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a C# SharpDX/MonoGame solution handy, but I have implemented this feature in my C++ [DeviceResources](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_uwp_dr/DeviceResources.cpp) that you could try to crib from.

1. You should first confirm that tearing support is available. Obtain a DXGI 1.5 interface (if available), and call `CheckFeatureSupport` for `DXGI_FEATURE_PRESENT_ALLOW_TEARING`. If it returns false or any of those steps fail, the system/driver doesn't support FreeSync/G-Sync.
2. If tearing is supported, you create your DXGI swap chain with the flag `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING`. Note that you also need to provide this flag when you call `ResizeBuffers`.
3. When you call `Present` use a interval of 0 and pass the flag `DXGI_PRESENT_ALLOW_TEARING`.

The documentation is on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt742104.aspx).