# How do I detect if the display has a variable refresh rate? (GSync, Freesync)

Tags: winapi, directx, screen

Displays can either use a fixed refresh rate (60Hz, 70Hz, 120Hz, 144Hz, 165Hz, etc), or a variable refresh rate through the use of GSync or Freesync.

I want to programmatically detect if the display's refresh rate is fixed or variable.  How do I detect this?

One possible way to detect this is to repeatedly page flip in a loop with Vsync Off, and see how many times it was able to page flip per second.  Without VFR support, you'd get screen tearing, and frame rates far exceeding the monitor's refresh rate (like 1000FPS), but with VFR support, it will delay until the monitor is ready for the next frame, so frame rate will be much lower.

Is there a more direct way to detect a Variable Frame Rate display?

Comment: If you own the swapchain, you should know wether you have enabled it or not using DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_TEARING? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45071415/how-can-i-disable-vsync-in-uwp

Comment: Maybe checking https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_5/ne-dxgi1_5-dxgi_feature could be helpful as `DXGI_FEATURE_PRESENT_ALLOW_TEARING` is labeled as [variable refresh rate displays requirement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/variable-refresh-rate-displays).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm concerned, you could get the RefreshRate from [DXGI_MODE_DESC structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb173064(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) via calling [IDXGIOutput1::GetDisplayModeList1 method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgioutput1-getdisplaymodelist1)